# App Crashes when button is pressed in fragment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crash, fragment

In my app fragment whenever I press the button, my app crashes. I have an edit text in which when the user will enter the text will go to firebase database after he/she presses the save button, but whenever I press the button my app crashes.

Here is the error message in logical window :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.fragment.NoteFragment$1.onClick(NoteFragment.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here is the code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.R;
import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.model.ModelNotes;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.model.model;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class NoteFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText e1;
    Button b1;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public NoteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static NoteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        NoteFragment fragment = new NoteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        e1 = view.findViewById(R.id.add_notes);
        b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String notes = e1.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!notes.isEmpty()) {
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notes");
                    ModelNotes Notes = new ModelNotes(notes);
                    databaseReference.setValue(Notes);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e1.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Enter Notes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest the solution, I have tried finding possible solutions on the web but not able to solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post `fragment_notes` layout so we can help

Answer (score 0):

It means you're trying to call the getText property accessor of an EditText when the EditText has not been instantiated, or you failed to get a valid reference to the EditText. I suppose this is the wrong piece of code:

```
e1 = view.findViewById(R.id.add_notes);
```

> findViewById

probably returns a null reference, maybe because the ID

> add_notes

is wrong ?

If I'm right, the following line actually throws the Null Pointer exception:

```
String notes = e1.getText().toString().trim();
```